# numpy compute lags between leader and lagger timestamps

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 arrays of timestamps

`leader = [1, 5, 15, 22]`

`lagger = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 17]`

I want to match every timestamp of the lagger with the one immediately preceding it in the leader and compute lags, obtaining the array

`lags = [2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2]`

Is there a quick manner to do with numpy/pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `searchsorted`, given that `lagger[0] > leader[0]`:

```
leader = np.array([1, 5, 15, 22])
lagger = np.array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 17])

lagger - leader[np.searchsorted(leader, lagger)-1]
```

Output:

```
array([2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it using masked arrays and subtractions:

```
np.ma.masked_less(np.subtract.outer(lagger,leader),1).min(1)
#[2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 2]
```

This finds subtraction between all leader and lagger and masks non-positive ones and then finds the minimum for each lagger.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `numpy` broadcast

```
[x[x>0].min() for x in lagger[:,None]-leader]
Out[107]: [2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2]
```